# Predict weekends three weeks ahead of last weekend that had a value, then every other three weeks, with conditional formatting

Tags: excel, offset, conditional-formatting

I need to predict three weeks in advance of weekends that have a 'Day Worked' (DW) value, and then every three weekends after using conditional formatting.

```
    A         B
01  06/10/18  DW
02  07/10/18  DW
03  08/10/18  NW
.   .         .
.   .         .
.   .         .
22  27/10/18 
23  28/10/18
```

As the 6th and 7th October were days worked, I'd like to use conditional formatting to change the cell colour of A22 and A23, and then the three weekends after that (A43, A44) and so on.

I can do the first three weeks after by using a simple OFFSET function but this doesn't help when predicting dates after that.

Comment: Why can't you condition format cells in column A where you have DW in column B ?

Comment: It would be for future dates where there isn't a value in column B yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not nice, but this formula in Conditional Formatting for cells in column A should do what you want:

```
=OR(
    MOD((A1-MAX($A$1:$A$999*($B$1:$B$999="DW")*(WEEKDAY($A$1:$A$999,2)=6))),21)=0,
    MOD((A1-MAX($A$1:$A$999*($B$1:$B$999="DW")*(WEEKDAY($A$1:$A$999,2)=7))),21)=0
)
```

This will highlight Saturdays or Sundays which are whole number multiples of 3 weeks away from the latest Saturday or Sunday with "DW" in Column B.

Change the 999 row reference(s) to suit your actual dataset.

**EDIT:**

This will only highlight when there is at least one Saturday / Sunday with "DW" in column B;

```
=OR(
    AND(
        MAX(($B$1:$B$999="DW")*(WEEKDAY($A$1:$A$999,2)=6)),
        MOD((A1-MAX($A$1:$A$999*($B$1:$B$999="DW")*(WEEKDAY($A$1:$A$999,2)=6))),21)=0
    ),
    AND(
        MAX(($B$1:$B$999="DW")*(WEEKDAY($A$1:$A$999,2)=7)),
        MOD((A1-MAX($A$1:$A$999*($B$1:$B$999="DW")*(WEEKDAY($A$1:$A$999,2)=7))),21)=0
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks this is great. The only problem I see with this is if the column had no 'DW'. I wouldn't want any date highlighted.

Comment: That's great. Thanks so much.